# RS232 bridge WiFi ESP32 problem.How avoid random data trough the serial?

Tags: c++, serial-port, esp32, freertos, arduino-esp32

First of all, thanks if anyone can help me.
Clarify that I am not an expert and any help/criticism is welcome.
The hw with which I communicate is not an ESP32, it is a board that has an interface to connect to it.
I have tried to put the involved parts of the code together for better understanding.
The program is expected to receive a string through the socket and record it in the serial, in turn printing the response.

Used material:

- ESP32-E.
- Rs232 to tll commercial module with max232 chip.
- USB-rs232 adapter for testing with putty and python.
- Null modem female-female adapter.

Tests carried out:

- Connection with putty.
- Connection with python script.
- View traffic with a logic analyzer.

Issues:

- When I connect from Putty or the python script with the USB adapter and with the null-modem adapter everything works as expected.
- When I connect to the esp32 script, I receive the "echoes" of what I transmit, and additional characters are being randomly recorded in the serial. I have checked with the logic analyzer and it really is like that. It doesn't always happen, it works as expected 80% of the time but therefore, it is not reliable.
- It is observed that if I do not record char by char with a small delay, the hw does not recognize the string.

Observations:

- It does not use DSR or RTS since they are set to False in the python script and it works perfectly.
- Although originally a nullmodem is used in the esp to be able to map the RX/Tx pins, in principle I think it does not affect me by not using the other control signals.
- At first I separated a task for writing and another for reading with a mutex, but the performance went down, I find everything in it more efficient.

Putty config:
[image: Putty config]

Below is the python code.

```
import serial
import time
import threading
import sys

port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
baudrate = 9600
byte_size = serial.EIGHTBITS
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
stop_bits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE

ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, bytesize=byte_size, parity=parity, stopbits=stop_bits, timeout=2,dsrdtr=False,rtscts=False)

lock = threading.Lock() 
#write thread
def sendBytes():
    global lock
    
    
    
    with lock:
        ser.write(b'\x03')
        ser.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    while True:
        user_input = input("\nInput the string to serial: \n")
        
        if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
            print("exit program.")
            sys.exit(0)
        
        with lock:
            if 'r'==user_input or user_input=='reset' :
                
                ser.write(b'\x03')
                ser.flush()
                
            else:
                ser.write((user_input + '\r').encode())
                ser.flush()
    
#read thread
def printData():
    global lock
            
    while True:
        
        data = ser.read_all()
        
        if data:
            cleaned_data = data.replace(b'\n', b'').replace(b'\r', b'')
            print(cleaned_data.decode('utf-8'))
        
        time.sleep(0.08)
        
        
taskRead = threading.Thread(target=printData)
taskWrite = threading.Thread(target=sendBytes)

taskRead.start()
taskWrite.start()
```

ESP32 code:

```
// custom struct to manage messages to queue
typedef struct 
{
    char str[100];
    int length;
}fixed_string_t;
// initzialice the socketserver
esp_err_t initServer(void)
{
    ws.begin();
    ws.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
    return ESP_OK;
}

// task for websocket loop
void runWebSocketServer(void *pv)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        ws.loop();
        vTaskDelay(5 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    }
}

esp_err_t pushToRs2Queue(fixed_string_t q)
{

    BaseType_t result = xQueueSend(rs232_queue, &q, portMAX_DELAY);
    return result == ESP_OK ? ESP_OK : -1;
}
// manage websocket incoming messages
void webSocketEvent(uint8_t client, WStype_t type, uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
    if (type == WStype_TEXT)
    {
        std::string data_str(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), len);
        fixed_string_t item;
        strncpy(item.str, data_str.c_str(), sizeof(item.str) - 1);
        //ensure null termination
        item.str[sizeof(item.str) - 1] = '\0';
        item.length = data_str.length();
        pushToRs2Queue(item);
    }
}
// Start o reset the connection with HW
void resetConn(void)
{

    Serial2.write(0x03);
    vTaskDelay(200 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    Serial2.flush();
}

// reader and writter task
void readRs232(void *pvp)
{
    QueueHandle_t rs232_queue = (QueueHandle_t)pvp;

    resetConn();
    Serial2.setTimeout(100);
    for (;;)
    {

        fixed_string_t arr;
        if (xQueueReceive(rs232_queue, &arr, pdMS_TO_TICKS(50)) == pdTRUE)
        {

            string toWrite = arr.str;
            if (!toWrite.empty() && toWrite[0] == 'c')
            {
                resetConn();
            }
            else
            {

                for (const char &c : toWrite)
                {
                    Serial2.write(c);
                    vTaskDelay(35 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                }
                // line feeder
                Serial2.write(0x0D);
            }
        }

        int bufferLen = Serial2.available();
        if (bufferLen)
        {
            Serial.println(Serial2.readString());
        }
    }
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial)
        ;
    ConnectWiFi_STA();
    if (initServer() == ESP_OK)
    {
        xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(&runWebSocketServer, "websocket_server", 5048, NULL, 5, NULL, 1);
    }
    Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, TXD2, RXD2);
    while (!Serial2);
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(&readRs232, "readRs2", 10048, rs232_queue, 10, &rs232ReadHandle, tskNO_AFFINITY);
}
void loop() {}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Well, giving it some thought, I remembered that something similar happened to me with CAN BUS communication.
Avoiding using the Arduino implementation (Serial class) and using the ESP-IDF one, it works perfectly, it no longer sends random bytes, it fires the events correctly, etc.
I don't know if it's because it's specifically for the hardware or because it has more control over it, but it works perfectly.

I leave a sample code in case it ever happens to someone and is interested.

```
void read_tsk(void *pvParameters)
{
// task containing a queue to print in a decoupled manner
toDebug("STarted");
uart_event_t event;
uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)malloc(1024); // data buffer
resetConn();

for (;;)
{

    if (xQueueReceive(xRS232Queue, (void *)&event, 
    portMAX_DELAY))
    {

        switch (event.type)
        {

        // data received
        case UART_DATA:
        {
            uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data, event.size, 
   portMAX_DELAY);

            std::string receivedData(reinterpret_cast<char *> 
  (data), event.size);

            toDebug(receivedData.c_str());
            break;
        }

        // Manage rest of events
        case UART_BREAK:
        case UART_PARITY_ERR:
        case UART_FRAME_ERR:
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
 }
  free(data);
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
 }



esp_err_t selectRS2Config(void)
{
bool installed = false;
const uart_config_t uart_config = {
    .baud_rate = 9600,
    .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
    .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
    .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
    .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE};
// Config uart params and pins no DSR no RTS
uart_param_config(UART_NUM_1, &uart_config);
uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_1, RXD2, TXD2, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, 
UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);
// install driver
if (uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_1, 1024 * 2, 1024 * 2, 10, 
&xRS232Queue, 0) == ESP_OK)
{
    toDebug("Driver installed,launching task");
    installed = true;
}
else
{
    toDebug("Uart driver cannot install", true, ERROR_D);
}

if (installed)
{
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(read_tsk, "read_tsk", 4096, NULL, 
12, 
&rs232ReadHandle, tskNO_AFFINITY);

    return ESP_OK;
}
return -1;
}



esp_err_t writeToUart(const fixed_string_t &arr)
{
// Send data
int result = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, arr.str, arr.length);
return (result > 0) ? ESP_OK : -1;
}



void resetConn(void)
{
fixed_string_t reset = {.str = {0x03}, .length = 1};
while (writeToUart(reset) != ESP_OK)
{
    vTaskDelay(200 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    toDebug("resend");
}
}
```